# Sandcastle Authoring for Conceptual Topics

Tags: sandcastle, maml, shfb

I'm working on writing some conceptual documentation to our otherwise technical documentation that is being produced in Sandcastle.

There aren't a whole lot of good examples/links out there, but I'm starting to get the hang of MAML.  If anyone has any excellent resources for looking/understanding this, I'd appreciate it.

I was hoping to have my conceptual documentation make reference to some of the types in my Documentation Sources.  Is there a way to put something as simple as ">Type to link to the documentation that is also in the code?

EDIT:
This was a major problem on my behalf, since I'm new to it.

The best way to link to a code item is to grab it from the Entities Window.  To open the Entities Window, go to Window > Entities References.  From here, you can Find the appropriate type/method/property and drag it into the code from the results.

The MAML reference guide is included with the Sandcastle Styles download: http://sandcastlestyles.codeplex.com/ and has been IMMENSELY helpful at learning how to format things.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a reference from Conceptual Documentation to Reference Documentation by using codeEntityReference. Details please refer to: http://davesexton.com/blog/blogs/blog/archive/2008/05/24/maml-migration-the-next-step-in-the-evolution-of-help-authoring.aspx